# how does componentDidUpdate get the updated dom element even though it has not changed on screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs

While going through the hooks documentation I stumbled upon how the timing of useLayoutEffect is same as componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate. I'm having trouble understanding the behavior of this phase. Since this phase is synchronous with the paint phase, I set out to test a hypothesis.

If I update the height of an element in render and componentDidUpdate runs synchronously with paint then when I read the element's height it should not be updated with the latest value. As I understand reflow/paint will happen only once React writes to the DOM.

So to test how this phase behaves I created the following element

````
```<div id="random_test_dummy" style={{height: `${this.state.heightRandom}px`}}></div>```
````

Initialized the heightRandom in the constructor as follows:

````
```this.state={heightRandom: 5};```
````

I then setup a setInterval call like this:

````
```componentWillMount() {
    this.clearInterval = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState((prevState) => ({heightRandom: prevState.heightRandom+5}));
    }, 10000);
  }```
````

So basically every 5 seconds I update the height of *random_test_dummy* element by 5px.

Now I setup the following code in componentDidUpdate

````
```componentDidUpdate() {
    alert(document.getElementById("random_test_dummy").clientHeight);
  }```
````

Now when my code runs, the alert says **10**, however the screen hasn't updated and it's height is **5px** in the *elements* tab in chrome DevTools.

I fail to understand how can the height read from the DOM be updated but the node on the screen not be updated. If i remove the alert and add a debug point on a console.log() statement, then the DOM node updates on the screen. How does this synchronous updating phase actually behave?

Comment: Your div is emtpy tho

Comment: @raven yup, purposely done. I just wanted to check when the height updates: during componentDidUpdate or after and if there's a visual change (Another element just below this div helps understand the visual change)

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding. The reason why the update dom measurements are done is because componentDidUpdate runs before the full paint is done, the measurements are there but the visual feedback is not because browser has not yet painted the changes